# Let $X$ be a compact hausdroff toplogical space and $Y$ be topological space such that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is bijective and continuos

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following option are correct
1) f is open map
2) f is a close map
3) f is both open and close
4) f is neither open, nor close

My approach: Since nothing has been said about $Y$, I assume $Y =X$ with trivial topology (i.e. Y and $\emptyset$). From this it follows that 4) is correct.

I was wondering if there is a more correct-proof based reasoning to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is right. Certainly for any Y, we can not conclude any option, but if you assume that Y is Hausdorff, then you can say 1), 2) and 3) are correct.

Comment: I don't see how to we come at such a conclusion, it's closed map because of haudroff (compact are closed) but I don't see why it's open?

Comment: See if you assume Y is Hausdorff, then take any closed set say V, then V is compact since X is compact and f(V) is compact and since Y is  Hausdorff so f(V) is closed. Similarly take any open set U, then It’s complement is closed and hence compact in X, and hence by previous one f(U) is open

Comment: Option 4 is also false.  That is, we  cannot conclude from the conditions that $f$ must be neither an open nor closed map.